# Will elementary OS Loki support fglrx?

Tags: graphics, amd

On Ubuntu 16.04, `fglrx` is not supported.

Since elementary OS Loki uses Ubuntu 16.04 as its base, will elementary OS Loki support `fglrx` or not?

Answer (score 2):

No.

AMD dropped the `flgrx` support for the version of the Xorg server that Ubuntu 16.04 ships with.

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2016-March/016315.html

Answer (score -1):

Question should be will Loki support AMD GPU Pro. It is supposedly better than fglrx.